# Decoupling too complex javascript modules

Tags: javascript, architecture, module, scalability, decoupling

Right now I'm developing pretty huge and complex webapp and have to deal with a huge amount of client-side js code, and to make my life easier I'm trying to decouple this code as much as I can.

I was hugely inspired by Nicholas Zakas (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw) and Addy Osmani (http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript) talk about scalable js architecture and was trying to apply some of their ideas to my work.

I've separated all my code across the multiple **independent modules**, and handle all intercommunications with some sort of **mediator**. This approach worked great in most cases. But there are some cases where I think **its not enough**.

One of the modules I'm working on represents a pretty complex list-alike structure. Here some simplified example:

[image: very simplified example]

Besides some rendering logic, module responsible for this piece of page should handle:

- pagination
- toggling groups
- moving elems and groups around with dnd
- cutting / copying / pasting elems and groups
- refreshing certaing groups / elems
- some logic within elems
- may be more stuff in nearest future

I had carried out all the unrelated logic that I could (for example editing and deleting logic is carried out to another module via events), but module size is still large (over 1K lines of code), and I dont know how reduce it. Moreover I'm using module pattern for my modules so it's even harder to separate logic between multiple files.

So I came here to ask is there any way to decouple complex logic **within a single module**?

**UPDATE:**

I want to clarify something. I'm pretty aware of how I can separate modules("module" from a module pattern) across multiple files  **in my code**.

But what I really searching for is the **new *logical* way to separate concerns within a single module** ("module" from NKZ presentation).

Comment: you question is a bit vague, but in general, you can treat a module like a program, and within the walls of the module you can create sub-modules, classes, types, and pure functions to help reduce the clutter.  self-contained modules are typically relatively expensive, owing to reduced internal procedure recycling; ex: a standalone list sorter compared to a jQuery plugin. Modules are better than a mess, so you're on the right track. Mastering the concepts of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control is likely needed to take your scripting to the next level.

Comment: People interested in this topic might want to check out [t3](http://t3js.org/), a JS framework recently released by Nicolas Zakas himself and his team at Box, that stems directly from the concepts outlined in the presentation linked in the question. [Here's](https://www.box.com/blog/introducing-t3-enabling-large-scale-javascript-applications/) a blog post from Zakas introducing it.

Comment: Hi, this is a bit late but might be helpful somehow. https://pogsdotnet.blogspot.sg/2017/07/modular-javascript-architecture.html

Answer (score 1):

To decouple a single module into multiple files I would recommend using the Augmentation pattern found on this page http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Additionally, here are some more resources on creating scalable JS applications:

Here is a video of a presentation given by Nicholas Zakas on "Creating A Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture." http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BGvy-S-Iag

Another good resource http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Knowing these concepts will allow you to build an application that is capable of dropping modules in and out seamlessly. You will be able to change a module without affecting any other module because your program will be loosely coupled. Additionally, should you choose to switch a base library, for example KnockoutJS to Angular, this framework will allow you to swap the base library easily and without breaking very much of your code.

Also, using modules and a mediator or sandbox will make your code easier to test. Testing is important in any non-trivial application. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Spencer. At first, I was aware of Augmention pattern, but I prefer to stay away from it because using it I can't leverage some features of module pattern. For example I can't have truly private scope for some var and functions. But, actually, I can't think of a better solution for splitting a module (from a module pattern) across multiple files. Secondly I've already mentioned approach of  Nicholas Zakas and Addy Osmani of building scalable js apps, and I've already make use of it.

Comment: And the last one. Knockout or Angular of course will make my life easier. A bit. But another cool framework will not solve the problem of a huge concentration of logic in one place.

Comment: Oops! I missed the part where you said you have read up on the two sources I provided! Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a better way to break apart modules into separate files other than using the augmentation pattern.